# Toilet Not emptying Certain Times of Day

Tags: plumbing

My toilet works perfectly about half the time. some times it take 2 or 3 flushes to empty contents whether it is tissue or poop. I am thinking the time it fails to empty might be connected to how many other people might be also using the system (showers, drains,etc). My plumbing under the house is 50 years old. Showers and sink drains empty quickly. I have used acid several times and cleaned the jets with wire. Didn't help. I did have to replace the tank(old one cracked) with a water safer a few years ago.The toilet is probably 50 years old. I have been looking around for a replacement toilet. It hard to find one small enough to fit in my small bathroom. Any thoughts whats causing intermittent incomplete flushes or replacement small toilets?

Comment: Upstairs toilet or downstairs toilet? It sounds like your septic tank could be full or your leach field is clogged. If it's accessible then open your septic tank's lid and see what's going on. You may need to call a professional...

Comment: Also, you put acid into your septic system?!?! You're practically asking for the system to fail. A septic tank works when there is living poop bacteria properly breaking down solids. Last I checked acid is harmful to that ecosystem.

Comment: If the toilet was not designed for a water saver tank, the replacement tank may not provide enough water for a good flush?

Comment: Please clarify: does water vacate the bowl slowly (ie the level in the bowl rises quickly upon flushing, then falls slowly) or is the problem more about flush water entering the bowl slowly (or insufficient volume of flush water)?

Comment: Are there two separate sewer systems in your home.  Years ago we had that, the sinks etc went to the leach field, the sanitary went to the septic tank. I Know izzy is correct, the best solution is to replace the toilet.

Comment: Probably an issue with bowl vs tank. They are designed to work together.

Comment: I am on city sewer system, no septic tank. The nearest sewer man hole is less than 200 feet from my one bathroom house.  The manhole empties quickly downstream and has never backed up with sewage. I guess there could be some back pressure during peak usage in the community.

Comment: At times water fills bowl quickly and fails to drain out completely. Later the same day the bowl fills quickly and empties quickly and completely.

Comment: I have been looking at the Kohler san souchi small toilet as replacement. Its nearly $700.00 pus installation charge. Any ideas about a similar small toilet in lower price range?

Comment: I suggest that you should snake ALL of the house septic vent pipes, and consider a cleanout run with an auger down all drains. I've seen dead rats caught in the vent stacks cause this kind of weird problem, as well as rusty drain pipes and loss of flow.